# Return macro from macro in Clojure

Tags: macros, clojure

As written in another post I am writing a Shen compiler in Clojure.
For that I need a macro/function that receives a symbol as parameter and if a Shen function is bound to it it returns the function and if the symbol is defined as Clojure macro it should return the macro, so `((function or) true false)` should give the same result as `(or true false)`.

My macro currently looks like:

```
(defmacro kl/function [x] 
(cl/let [fn (symbol (cl/str (name x) "__fnPoF__"))]
    (if (function? fn) `(eval ~fn) `(quote ~x))))
```

The "__fnPoF__" postfix is there because of the double namespace in Shen. (A value and a function can be assigned to the same symbol.)

My problem now is that `((function or) true false)` evaluates to false because it evaluates as `('or true false)` but if I leave out the "quote" (`x` instead of `` `(quote ~x) `` I get the following Exception:

```
kl=> (function *)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't take value of a macro: #'kl/*, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:8)
```

Does someone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can't "return" a macro, because macros have no value. But you can make (function or) expand to the symbol or; then the usual Clojure macroexpansion/evaluation mechanisms will do just what you want. So, while I don't know how Shen works, it seems like a simple change would be:

```
(defmacro kl/function [x] 
  (cl/let [fn (symbol (cl/str (name x) "__fnPoF__"))]
    (if (function? fn)
      `(eval ~fn)
      x)))
```

As an aside, that `eval` strikes me as a **disaster** waiting to happen. I strongly doubt that `eval` is necessary for your goals.

Comment: As I wrote above, if I replace ` `(quote x)` by `x` I get      `CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't take value of a macro: #'kl/*, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:8)`

Comment: @NameLess Wow, that's pretty interesting. It looks like the macroexpander sees that `((function when) ...)` doesn't have a macro as its first subform, so it gives up on macroexpanding. Then when the inner thing expands to `when`, it doesn't go back up. I'm not sure how you would deal with that.